# How to universally parse json into blocks using jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json

How to universally parse json to get from the html block [data-json Item], and insert the key into it?

my html, contains data-jsonItem (json - key,key2) and data-jsonValue (json - subObject):

```
<span data-jsonItem="key1" data-jsonValue="val"></span>
<span data-jsonItem="key1" data-jsonValue="val2"></span>
<span data-jsonItem="key2" data-jsonValue="val"></span>
<span data-jsonItem="key2" data-jsonValue="val2"></span>
```

my javascript

```
<script>
function jsonUPDATE() {
  var URL = "/json.json";
  $.getJSON(URL, function(data){
    $.each(data, function (item, value) {   
        var jsonItem = "key1";
        if (item == jsonItem) {
            $.each(value, function (i, object) {
                $.each(object, function (subI, subObject) {
                    $("[data-jsonValue='"+subI+"']").html(subObject);
                });
            });
        }
    });
  });
}
</script>
```

json:

```
{
    "key1": [
        {
            "val": 0, 
            "val2": 0, 
            "val3": 0, 
        }
    ], 
    "key2": [
        {
            "val": 0, 
            "val2": 0, 
            "val3": 0, 
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of looping through all items in the array of objects you could improve the efficiency of the logic and make it more succinct by instead looping through all the `span` elements and retrieving the data from the object directly, based on the `data` attributes on that `span`. Try this:

```js
var data = {
  "key1": [{
    "val": 1,
    "val2": 2,
    "val3": 3,
  }],
  "key2": [{
    "val": 4,
    "val2": 5,
    "val3": 6,
  }]
}

// in your AJAX callback:
$('span').html(function() {
  var $span = $(this)
  return data[$span.data('jsonitem')][0][$span.data('jsonvalue')];
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span data-jsonItem="key1" data-jsonValue="val"></span>
<span data-jsonItem="key1" data-jsonValue="val2"></span>
<span data-jsonItem="key2" data-jsonValue="val"></span>
<span data-jsonItem="key2" data-jsonValue="val2"></span>
```

Note that I changed the `valX` values in the objects to make the effect of this logic clearer.

Comment: could you tell me, please, and if he looks so:
{
  "key1":{
    "subkey1":[
      {
        "val":0,
        "val2":1
      },
          "subkey2":[
      {
        "val":2,
        "val2":3
      }
    ]  
  }
}

Comment: Assuming you only access `subkey1` from that structure then this will work: `data[$span.data('jsonitem')].subkey1[0][$span.data('jsonvalue')]`. If you need to access either of them then you'll need to write some more complex logic to determine which subkey needs to be used.

Comment: need to write a loop (.each)? for  <span data-jsonItem="key1" data-jsonSubItem="subkey1" data-jsonValue="val"></span>

Comment: In that case `data[$span.data('jsonitem')][$span.data('jsonsubitem')][0][$span.data('jsonvalue')]` would work